# Is there a TypeScript solution for ng-repeat listData[columnName], trying go convert to *ngFor listData[columnName]

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dynamic list component in JS.  You pass the data array and column headers you want to display and it will create only the column headers you want, then it gets each line of the data[header.columnName] and displays that on each line.  I store the headers for different lists in a database so they can be changed on the fly.  I am new to angujarJS and angular, so maybe I didn't do it the best way, but it worked pretty cool    until I met TypeScript.

I looked at many Pipes examples and (key,object) posts, but I'm not clear on how to make that work on this code.  The data is just a list of anything, like locations(locationId, locationName, description, skip1, skip2, etc.) and columnHeaders contains list of columns to display (locationId, locationName) and skips the rest.

```
<thead>
      <tr>
         <th ng-repeat="column in columnHeaders.headers | filter:visible=true    |  orderBy:'sortOrder'" class="stickyheader" ng-click="sortDataColumn(column.name)">{{column.columnName}}
            <span class="sortorder" ng-show="propertyName === column.name" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span></th>
         <th colspan={{operations}} class="stickyheader" ng-click="selectColumns()">&#9745;&nbsp; Operations</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody style="border: none">
      <tr style="border: none;" data-ng-click="select($index, aListData)"
          data-ng-repeat="aListData in listData  |  orderBy:propertyName:reverse  |  filter:searchValue">
         <!--   Special ng-class to set dark colors for the list when Light Theme Mode is applied -->
         <td ng-class="{'color-list': theme==1}" ng-repeat="column in columnHeaders.headers | orderBy:'sortOrder' | filter:visible=true">
<!--            <div>{{aListData[column.name]}}</div>-->
            <div ng-if="column.format=='text'">{{aListData[column.name]}}</div>
            <div ng-if="column.format=='date'">{{aListData[column.name] | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</div>
            <div ng-if="column.format=='dateTime'">{{aListData[column.name] | date:'MM/dd/yyyy h:mma'}}</div>
         </td>
```

The problem seems to be that you can't subscript the data object with a string that contains the actual column name, which pretty much breaks the whole idea.  Maybe there is a much better way to do this, but I'm trying to avoid custom coding for every list that comes up.  I also have a dynamic validation form that uses the same concept, so it would really be nice to get this working.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not sure how "let element" works just yet - but I was able to solve the problem.  So now in theory I "should" be able to pass a data source and desired columns into a component and reuse it for any list.

```
 listHeaders: DynamicListsDetailHeaders[] = [
    {columnName: 'appName',         columnLabel: 'App Name',},
    {columnName: 'dynamicListsId',  columnLabel: 'Id',},
    {columnName: 'listName',        columnLabel: 'List Name',},
    {columnName: 'listDescription', columnLabel: 'Description',},
    {columnName: 'lastUpdated',     columnLabel: 'Last Updated',},
  ];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['appName', 'dynamicListsId', 'listName', 'listDescription', 'lastUpdated'];


<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <div *ngFor="let displayColumn of listHeaders">

  <ng-container matColumnDef={{displayColumn.columnName}}>
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{displayColumn.columnLabel}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[displayColumn.columnName]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  </div>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```